# Time for UILocalNotification using UIStepper

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

It is necessary to send a reminder every day, at a set time. The time is set in the format from 1 to 24 hours using UIStepper. Modified code, but it still does not work, DO NOT COME NOTICES

```
var hour = 0.0
let notification = UILocalNotification()
@IBOutlet weak var remindStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet weak var remindLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var remindSwitch: UISwitch!
```

in viewDidLoad()

```
remindStepper.wraps = true
remindStepper.value = hour
remindStepper.minimumValue = 0
remindStepper.maximumValue = 24
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("hour") != nil  { hour = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("hour") as! Double }

if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("remindOnOff") != nil  { remindOnOff = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("remindOnOff") as! Bool
}
    if remindOnOff == true {
        remindSwitch.on = true
    } else {
        remindSwitch.on = false
    }
    remindLabel.text = "\(Int(hour)):00"
```

Then create

```
func setEveryDayNotification(){

  let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
  var dateFire = NSDate()
  let components = calendar.components(.Hour,fromDate: dateFire)
  components.calendar = calendar
  components.hour = Int(hour)
  dateFire = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!

  notification.alertTitle = "alert title"
  notification.alertBody = "alert body"
  notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
  notification.alertAction = "Run the workout"
  notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()
  notification.fireDate = components.date
  notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
 }
@IBAction func remindStepper(sender: UIStepper) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Int(sender.value), forKey: "hour")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    remindLabel.text = "\(Int(sender.value).description):00"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
    remindOnOff = false
    remindSwitch.on = false
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(remindOnOff, forKey: "remindOnOff")
}
    @IBAction func remindSwitch(sender: UISwitch) {
    if remindSwitch.on {
        setEveryDayNotification()
        remindOnOff = true
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(remindOnOff, forKey: "remindOnOff")
    } else {
        remindOnOff = false
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(remindOnOff, forKey: "remindOnOff")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code changes the year to 0000 so your notification is not set at the proper time

You can check the following code , replace the current code

```
 let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
  var dateFire = NSDate()
  let components = calendar.components(.Hour,fromDate: dateFire)
  components.calendar = calendar
  components.hour = Int(hour)
  dateFire = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
```

with the below code

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
let dateFire = NSDate()
let newDate = calendar.dateBySettingHour(Int(hour), minute:00, second:00, ofDate: dateFire, options:NSCalendarOptions())
```

And at time of notification fire data make it like this

```
notification.fireDate = newDate
```

If you put this code your local notification should be set

**Note:** As per your current code you are calling the `setEveryDayNotification` at the everytime the stepper value is changed so it will set the notification for the every hour based on the stepper value, instead of that you should make separate button which can get the stepper current value and set the notification for the current selected hour only.

Comment: can you help me to realize my task right? Thank you

Comment: @ArturSkachkov did you tried the code i have written, that should help you ?

Comment: notification will trigger once. further change the value hour and nothing happens :(

Comment: @ArturSkachkov did you change the way you are setting the notifications?  as I said in the note the current mechanism in your code is not proper you should keep some separate button like which will set the notification at selected time

Comment: I added a button switch. When running on a device alert is triggered repeatedly at the expiration of an hour for several hours

Comment: UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification) - This line removes the warning, or it may not work properly?

Comment: @ArturSkachkov how you are getting "notification" object for the remove , you can try like this to remove all notification `UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelAllLocalNotifications()` or you have to get notification object which is already set you can't cancel the notification object which in not set yet

Comment: Do not really understand. Replaced everywhere was UIApplication.sharedApplication (). CancelLocalNotification (notification) on UIApplication.sharedApplication (). CancelAllLocalNotifications () and now notified all stopped coming. Again, obviously do not correctly :)

Comment: I do not understand, I'm in "if remind Switch.on {set EveryDay Notification ()}" notification shall include

Comment: @ArturSkachkov can you explain your full scenario of what you want to implement here or in the answer so I can explain more clearly

Comment: I want to remindStepper using a user selects the required time for the reminder, which will be repeated every day at the same time, when the remindSwitch this notification is activated, when you turn off the notification remindSwitch removed. If you change the values remindStepper previous notification is removed and off remindSwitch. Thank you